# Heroku: heroku is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: heroku, command-line, heroku-cli

As you can probably tell by the title, I am having difficulty with Heroku. Whenever I run `heroku --version` in the Command Line, I receive the error `'heroku' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` I have tried uninstalling and re-installing heroku multiple times, to no success. I have included screenshots of the download steps which I took.

Specs:

- Windows v10.0.18363.1198, 64-bit
- heroku CLI v7.47.3
- Git v2.29.2.windows.2

Download Steps:

1. [image: Heroku Setup Step 1]
2. [image: Heroku Setup Step 2]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that you add the path to heroku to PATH. In this case it would be `C:\Program Files (x86)\heroku\client\bin`

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you restart your system and run your command again, worked for me earlier.

After the restart, check your Heroku version use `heroku -v` in terminal or CMD.